# I want to know how to write a method that returns the sum of all integers from 1 up to the number passed as parameter

Tags: c#, console-application

I am taking a class teaching C# and we just learned about methods. I am very, very new at this. As an assignment, it says the following:

"Write a method 'SumNum' that accepts an integer parameter and returns the sum of all the integers from 1 up to the number passed as an argument. For example, if you pass 20 as an argument, the method will return the sum of 1, 2, 3, 4,...20 which is 210."

I've been trying to come up with something but I can't figure it out and I keep getting error messages. I know how to create a method but I don't know how to do mathematical operations with a changing amount of integers.

This is all I've been able to come up with:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lab6
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static int SumNum(int num)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Sum1 = SumNum(20);
            Console.WriteLine(Sum1);
        }
        
    }
}
```

The error says "Not all code paths return a value."

Comment: What happens if the parameter `num` is `-1`. How many times will your `for` loop execute, and what will be `return`ed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote "in SumNum method, return `i` inside the for loop".
This means that it won't return the sum of integers from `1` up to your input parameter `num` because you never do the actual sum.

The error says:

> Not all code paths return a value.

When the input parameter is less than zero in your code, program won't go inside for-loop and won't execute the `return i;` line. That error is shown because of that possible case.

You can try the code below:

```
   static int SumNum(int num)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            sum += i;
        }

        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Nice answer. I would suggest you to also explain the error message OP had "_Not all code paths return a value_". Explain in what scenario the original code would not return anything.

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure but I guess the reason would be that input parameter could be less than zero(0). In that case, the program won't go inside for-loop and it won't come to 'return' line.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do to solve this problem is use a loop that increments up until the parameter "range" that is in your method signature. The below is a solution using a for loop and where I have "sum += i;", its just a short hand of writing "sum = sum + i;"

```
public int CalculateSum(int maxRange)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= maxRange; i++)
    {
        sum += i
    }
    
    return sum;
}
```

Just to add an explanation of the error you getting as well, if you declare a method as "public int SumNum()", you are telling the compiler that this method returns an int so at the end of that method you would end it with the return keyword followed by an int data type. If you wanted to declare a method that did not return anything and just did logic then your method signature would include a "void"

eg:

```
public void SumNum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has few problems.

Error message says that there is a path in which your code is not retuning the value.

Just imaging the case when user enters number -1, will your code return anything?

You also have to think about big number like `int.Max`, how your code will behave?

What if number is so big that the sum exceeds the `int.Max` value?

And at last, as an alternative approach, sum of the whole numbers from 1 to n is n(n+1)/2.

I would suggest here to use `uint` in place of `int`.

For very large numbers there is a different story, like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-two-large-numbers/amp/).